# Ubuntu on HP desktop rp5800 not booting

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I loaded 32 bit 14.04.1 Ubuntu into an HP desktop that originally had Windows 7 Professional but currently has no Operating Software. It would appear that I completed it correctly. On Restart I got past the log in and the password. Then I got kris@ubuntunomotos:”$ and do not know where to go to from here. I am a million years old and extremely poor at this Klingon stuff. Please explain it to me like I am a very slow 4 year old. Many thanks! Kris

Comment: Did you install the Ubuntu server version? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/964039/edit) the question above and add the exact name of the ISO file you downloaded and installed.

Comment: 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image

Comment: 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image is the one that i downloaded and installed

Comment: correction - i believe that the software i downloaded was for a server

Comment: my profound apologies - i believe that i was correct the first time - not for a server

Comment: For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.

Comment: did you choose a desktop when you were installing?

Comment: as i said i am extremely poor at this. i looked at the dvd of the ubuntu i burned and loaded and it is in fact for a server. do i simply start over burning the correct ubuntu and then loading it or do i have to do something with the incorrect server ubuntu that i already loaded in the desktop?

Comment: ok i now have the correct ubuntu. before i load it into the desktop do i need to do something with the incorrect ubuntu that i previously loaded or will it all resolve itself with no help from me?

Comment: It was suggested that I load either 16 or 17. In Vancouver there is Ubuntu Volunteer Support. It took 3 guys to load 14 alongside the Windows 8 in my Laptop. In the past I had been able to load my own Ubuntu. W8 was designed to make the loading of any other software impossible for nonpros. In Edmonton there is no Support. I had to pay to load 16 into 2 old Desktops. The 16 in both units was unstable. I had to pay to remove the 16 and load 14. Both are now working perfectly. I loaded 14 into this newest old Desktop. It was easy and now working perfectly. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would go to this site and download Ubuntu mate from here. Just follow the directions to find what you need:
https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/index.html